# Install-ChocolateyPackage credential arguement

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I am trying to download 'msi' file from given url (www.abc.com), but need to pass credential in order to access the url. Without credential, I am getting the following error message.

```
Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
```

According to the 'Install-ChocolateyPackage" support doc, they don't provide argument for credentail. Any idea?

https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-package

Comment: Does the package not exist in the Chocolatey Repository already?

Comment: Perhaps you can use `-options` to supply credentials. It accepts a hashtable. You can make a header depending on the type of auth the site accepts